# Skip duplicate values when importing CSV data

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a **csv** file with **2** columns (Company Name, Customer Name). I insert company_name in **tbl_company** and customer_name and company_id in **tbl_customer**. So company_id is the foreign key in tbl_customer. Now the problem I am facing is that I dont want to insert company name more than 1 time in my tbl_company. Can anyone please check the code where I write this condition.

My PHP code

```
$filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        $x = 0;
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
                    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
                    if($x > 0) {
                    // Insert company name into company table
                    $sql_comp = "INSERT into tbl_company(company_name) values ('$emapData[0]')";
                    mysql_query($sql_comp);
                    //$lastID = mysql_insert_id();
                    // get last ID from tbl_company and insert as foreign key in tbl_customer
                    $sql_LID = "SELECT * FROM tbl_company ORDER BY id DESC";
                    $res_LID = mysql_query($sql_LID);
                    $row_LID = mysql_fetch_array($res_LID);
                    $lastID = $row_LID['id'];
                    // insert company id and customer name into table customer
                    $sql_cust = "INSERT into tbl_customer(comp_id,customer_name) values ('$lastID', '$emapData[1]')";
                    mysql_query($sql_cust);
                    }
                    $x++;
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
```

Comment: Question might be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the best way, but you could do devise something like this:

```
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

    while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        $company_name = $emapData[0];

        // checking
        // get ID from tbl_company and insert as foreign key in tbl_customer
        $sql_LID = "SELECT * FROM tbl_company WHERE company_name = '$company_name'";
        $res_LID = mysql_query($sql_LID);


        if(mysql_num_rows($res_LID) <= 0) {
            // if does not exist
            // Insert company name into company table
            $sql_comp = "INSERT into tbl_company(company_name) values ('$company_name')";
            mysql_query($sql_comp);   
            $lastID = mysql_insert_id();

        } else {
            $row_LID = mysql_fetch_array($res_LID);
            $lastID = $row_LID['id'];
        }


        // insert company id and customer name into table customer
        $sql_cust = "INSERT into tbl_customer(comp_id,customer_name) values ('$lastID', '$emapData[1]')";
        mysql_query($sql_cust);


    }
    fclose($file);
    echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: I tried it and its working for company insertion but it donot insert the correct company_id into tbl_customer. for exapmle if microsoft is on line 2 and line 5 on CSV file, I want to insert microsoft 1 time with ID 2 and insert that ID for every customer whose company is Microsoft. But now its take the last id without comparing customer and company name of CSV file.

Comment: @Shams ahh okay you need those company id, then check my revision, should be able to get those

Comment: is there anyway to get the id of company by company name instead of getting the last ID, i think that is the area where I can solve foreign key issue but I dont know how exactly?

Comment: @Shams did you try my revision? that should be enough, but if you really want that route, which i wouldn't advice, you could select every loop for that company name, but that would be unwise since you're going to select every loop

Comment: can you give me your email, I will send you tables and CSV file so you will understand well

Comment: you code is working perfect for the company but its not entering correct values in tbl_customer as company_id

Comment: @Shams you really don't have to, i would just like to know if my revision worked fine. i changed my answer a little bit

Comment: @Shams ow okay, then i guess you could try to modify my answer, create another select statement for each iteration for checking

Comment: its perfect now but if someone select the csv file again and press upload button then it allow duplicate entry into tbl_company. Can we stop it by anyway?

Comment: @Shams yes i could change this a little bit, just a sec

Comment: it create duplicate value to company but in customer table its fine, it pass correct value as a foreign key, so for the duplicate company, it donot add any customer instead it assign customer to company which we inserted first

Comment: @Shams could you try my revision again. lets see if its okay

Comment: yes its great now, working perfect. Thank you for the help, I was stuck in that from yesterday :)

Comment: @Shams sure im glad it turned out well, glad to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Map the CSV file to an array using the line below:

`$array = array_map('str_getcsv', file('filename.csv'));`

You can then iterate over that array and insert a row into your database in a `foreach` loop.

Ex:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $update = $db->prepare('UPDATE table SET value = ? WHERE key = ?');
    $update->execute(array($val, $key));

}
```

To skip over duplicate records, create an empty array prior to entering the loop, and inside of the loop add a conditional to check if the value of the iteration is inside of the separate array like so:

```
$records = [];

//inside of foreach loop

if(!in_array($value, $records)) {
    //insert record
    $records[] = $value;
}
```

Also, try to refrain from using the mysql_* functions as they have been deprecated and are not the best available for communicating with your database.